# How can I deploy my express server - which uses graphql - to Heroku. Currently stuck on build

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, graphql

I am trying to deploy a personal project using React, NodeJS, GraphQL and  Heroku. This is the first time I use GraphQL and I'm feeling a little lost. I'm doing everything that I would normally do without using GraphQL, but Heroku gets stuck on the bulding phase. Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on? Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot!

This is my server

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const cors = require("cors");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
var schema = require("./schema/schema.js");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const db = require("../mongodb/index");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });

// console.log(server);
app.use(express.static("public"));

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: PORT }, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("there was an error", err);
  } else {
    console.log(`server ready at http://localhost:3002${server.graphqlPath}`);
  }
});
```

And my apolloClient in app.jsx looks like this

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "/graphql"
});
```

After I try to deploy using
`git push heroku master`

it takes a long time and I get the following

```
remote: webpack is watching the files…
remote:
remote:        Hash: ea7bec75c71b31ce8b50
remote:        Version: webpack 4.39.2
remote:        Time: 6998ms
remote:        Built at: 09/03/2019 4:19:47 AM
remote:            Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
remote:        bundle.js  12.4 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
remote:        Entrypoint main = bundle.js
remote:        [./client/index.jsx] 182 bytes {main} [built]
remote:        [./client/queries/queries.jsx] 1.68 KiB {main} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/moment/locale sync recursive ^\.\/.*$] ./node_modules/moment/locale sync ^\.\/.*$ 3 KiB {main} [optional] [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {main} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {main} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {main} [built]
remote:            + 873 hidden modules
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I was not able to find anything on this current problem. Has anyone faced a similar issue with Heroku?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: "webpack is watching the files…" from your log is concerning.  there is no reason for webpack to watch files in a production build step.  once that is sorted out, and the problem remains, try contacting heroku support.